# Simulate slow query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Does MongoDb have anything like MySql's `SELECT SLEEP(5);` ?

I can see some internal sleep function that would pause the whole server, but I need to pause just the current query.

Disclaimer: just for testing purposes

Comment: Are you trying to simulate a slow query?

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists atm, at least I have never heard of it. I suppose you could use a `$where` with some sneaky coding to make the JS thread sleep, but only for testing of course. However this will induce a sleep or `timeout()` per doc iteration of the find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [$where operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/#op._S_where) to call sleep().  This should work in any language or ORM/ODM.  For example, in Mongoid you could do:

```
Model.where( :$where => "sleep(100) || true" ).count
```

Tune the sleep value for the number of documents in the collection (it will delay on each one).  This will do fairly horrible things to the DB server, so only use it for testing, and never (ever!) on a production server.

Comment: in my question I mentioned that _sleep_ will pause the whole server, not just a single query

Comment: This doesn't pause the whole server (other queries will still run in between the calls to sleep on each document) but it does make it slower.

Comment: what's the unit of 100 ?  is it 100 seconds or 100 milliseconds?

Comment: @carton.swing 100ms. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sleep/index.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `$where` operator as [code_monkey_steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2340684/code-monkey-steve) says, but be sure you do with [mongo version >= 2.4](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#javascript-engine-changed-to-v8). Before that version no javascript can be run on parallel on the same server. The `sleep` command is javascript, so it would apparently block other javascript queries you could be making.

Answer (score 3):

from mongo Shell you can run :

```
db.collection_name.find( { $where: function() { return sleep(100) || true }}).pretty();
```

tested and working.

Comment: please do not run this in production, only for testing purpose in dev environment

Answer (score 2):

From the `mongo` shell you can do sleep( ms ), eg sleep for 5 seconds before running a query:

```
> sleep(5000); db.collection.find(..);
```

This doesn't pause the current query, but does pause execution on that connection for the specific number of milliseconds before continuing with the next statement (which is equivalent to a `select sleep(5)` in MySQL).